# How to drop a pin on the map on a particular place And draw route from user current location to that praticular place?

Tags: iphone, mapkit

IN my project I need to draw a route between two pins. Can anyone tell me what are the methods used. And give me the example code for that.

Comment: Try the response to this similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085749/google-map-route-draw-on-iphone

Answer (score 1):

Try these posts.. It will help you i think

http://navarra.ca/?p=786

http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=108

This will automatically use Google Direction API and will fetch the points in between the locations i guess..

Anyhow see this blog http://laurilarjo.wordpress.com/2010/10/23/using-google-directions-api-and-drawing-routes-in-iphone-mkmapview/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MKPolyLineView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPolylineView_class/Reference/Reference.html) - it allows you to draw a line (or polyline, if you need several segments) as an overlay on top of the MKMapView. Apple even has example code using this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KMLViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010046).

Note that this method uses an MKOverlayView which was added in iOS 4, so it only works in iOS 4+. If you need to target iOS 3 devices, then you can use the MKAnnotationView hack that others have linked to (originating as far as I can tell from [that spitzkoff blog post](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=108)). I used to do it that way, but did away with it when iOS 4 had matured enough - I'd wholeheartedly recommend doing it the new way if you don't need iOS 3 support.

As for pins, use [MKPinAnnotationView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPinAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score -1):

Go to google maps. "Get directions". Make a screenshot. Then use UIImageView. This is what I would do.