# MKMapView Routeline is off the road

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4

I have implemented a method that draw the route between 2 points, but the route is off the road. How can I draw the route only in road?

```
coordinateArray[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(appDelegate.latitude, appDelegate.longitude);
coordinateArray[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(appDelegate.latitude2, appDelegate.longitude2); 

self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray count:2];
[self.myMapView setVisibleMapRect:[self.routeLine boundingMapRect]]; 
[self.myMapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085749/google-map-route-draw-on-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was very helpful ((: MKPolyline with Google Maps API
https://github.com/Surya121/SBMapWithRoute